# xml loop to last node and insert c#

Tags: c#, xml

i'm looping through xml and i want to insert data after the last  node.

this is the xml and the code i have so far

any help would be great

```
        <User Name="">
        <Option Name="Pass"></Option>
        <Option Name="Group"></Option>
        <Option Name="Bypass server userlimit">0</Option>
        <Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>
        <Option Name="IP Limit">0</Option>
        <Option Name="Enabled">1</Option>
        <Option Name="Comments"></Option>
        <Option Name="ForceSsl">0</Option>
        <IpFilter>
            <Disallowed />
            <Allowed />
        </IpFilter>
        <Permissions>
            <Permission Dir="kk"
                <Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>
            </Permission>
        </Permissions>
    </User>
</Users>
```

```
 XmlDocument xdcDocument = new XmlDocument();

    xdcDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Rob\Desktop\filezilla.xml");


    XmlElement xelRoot = xdcDocument.DocumentElement;
    XmlNodeList xnlNodes = xelRoot.SelectNodes("/User");

    foreach (XmlNode xNode in xnlNodes)
    {
        //how do i loop to the user node and then insert afterwards?
    }
```

Comment: 1) Your XML is invalid, it's missing a `<Users>` at the beginning.  2) It's unclear from your question where in the XML hierarchy you want to insert your node.  Can you also show the XML you are trying to create?

Comment: Close the Permission node (with:  > ) as well please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your XML must be valid, I have added 2 fixes to your XML, you would get the exception telling you where exactly the error is.

```
    <Users>

       <User Name="">
        <Option Name="Pass"></Option>
        <Option Name="Group"></Option>
        <Option Name="Bypass server userlimit">0</Option>
        <Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>
        <Option Name="IP Limit">0</Option>
        <Option Name="Enabled">1</Option>
        <Option Name="Comments"></Option>
        <Option Name="ForceSsl">0</Option>
        <IpFilter>
            <Disallowed />
            <Allowed />
        </IpFilter>
        <Permissions>
            <Permission Dir="kk">
                <Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>
            </Permission>
        </Permissions>
    </User>
</Users>
```

The code that would do what you are asking for:

```
 XmlDocument xdcDocument = new XmlDocument();

                xdcDocument.Load("filezilla.xml");

                XmlElement xelRoot = xdcDocument.DocumentElement;

                // select the last node of type User
                XmlNodeList xmlNodes = xelRoot.SelectNodes("/Users/User[last()]");


                if (xmlNodes.Count == 1)
                {
                    var node = xmlNodes[0];

                    // create your new node, whatever structure you want
                    var element = xdcDocument.CreateElement("NodeAfterLastUser");

                    // insert this node to the same parent after the last user
                    node.ParentNode.InsertAfter(element, node);

                    xdcDocument.Save("filezilla_result.xml");
                }
```

Result:

```
<Users>
  <User Name="">
    <Option Name="Pass">
    </Option>
    <Option Name="Group">
    </Option>
    <Option Name="Bypass server userlimit">0</Option>
    <Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>
    <Option Name="IP Limit">0</Option>
    <Option Name="Enabled">1</Option>
    <Option Name="Comments">
    </Option>
    <Option Name="ForceSsl">0</Option>
    <IpFilter>
      <Disallowed />
      <Allowed />
    </IpFilter>
    <Permissions>
      <Permission Dir="kk">
        <Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>
      </Permission>
    </Permissions>
  </User>
  <NodeAfterLastUser />
</Users>
```

Key notes:
the selection of last user node made by XPath syntax: /Users/User[last()]
You can find here more examples and explanation about selections:
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Then just add the element that you want, I created in my example element with name NodeAfterLastUser for illlustration, but here where your node should be actually placed.

Good luck.

Comment: works perfectly,thank you so much, i understand so much more now.

Comment: one more question how would i add in the below

Comment: Where? I dont sure I got what you mean?

Comment: sorry it didnt post, if i wanted to add in something like this, would i need to do multiple Create.Elements? `<User Name="">
        <Option Name="Pass"></Option>
        <Option Name="Group"></Option>
        <Option Name="Bypass server userlimit">0</Option></User>`

Comment: Yes, if you create an Element with child elements and Attributes, you have to use multiple times: xdcDocument.CreateElement and xdcDocument.CreateAttribute methods and then insert them in the location that you wish

Answer (score 1):

Your xml is not valid. After fixing it as:

```
<Users>
       <User Name="">
        <Option Name="Pass"></Option>
        <Option Name="Group"></Option>
        <Option Name="Bypass server userlimit">0</Option>
        <Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>
        <Option Name="IP Limit">0</Option>
        <Option Name="Enabled">1</Option>
        <Option Name="Comments"></Option>
        <Option Name="ForceSsl">0</Option>
        <IpFilter>
            <Disallowed />
            <Allowed />
        </IpFilter>
        <Permissions>
            <Permission Dir="kk">
                <Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>
            </Permission>
        </Permissions>
    </User>
</Users>
```

You can use Linq2Xml

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
xDoc.XPathSelectElement("/Users") //Find parent Node
    .Add( new XElement("NewNode","NewValue")); //Add to parent as its last child
var newxml = xDoc.ToString();
```

The output is:

```
<Users>
  <User Name="">
    <Option Name="Pass"></Option>
    <Option Name="Group"></Option>
    <Option Name="Bypass server userlimit">0</Option>
    <Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>
    <Option Name="IP Limit">0</Option>
    <Option Name="Enabled">1</Option>
    <Option Name="Comments"></Option>
    <Option Name="ForceSsl">0</Option>
    <IpFilter>
      <Disallowed />
      <Allowed />
    </IpFilter>
    <Permissions>
      <Permission Dir="kk">
        <Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>
      </Permission>
    </Permissions>
  </User>
  <NewNode>NewValue</NewNode>
</Users>
```

PS: Don't forget to include the namespaces

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```